# Angular dialog and routing

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

What do i need to do to make the data appear on the dialog page? I want the path to change according to the post id.

My ts file is :

```
getReviewsByPostId(postId: string) {
    this.reviewService.getReviewsByPostId(postId).subscribe((data) => {
      if (!data.isSuccessful) {
        return;
      }
      console.log(postId);
      console.log(data);
      this.reviews = data.data;
    });
  }
```

---

my html page is:

````
  <div>
    <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap" *ngFor="let review of reviews">
      <div class="flex flex-row flex-1 items-center">
        <div mat-card-avatar class="rounded-full overflow-hidden mx-2 "><img [src]="review.auth?.avatar"></div>
        <mat-card-title class="font-medium text-sm pb-3">{{review.auth?.username}}
        </mat-card-title>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-col flex-1 text-right">
        <mat-card-subtitle class="text-sm">{{review.createdAt | date:'dd/MM/yy'}} {{review.createdAt |
          date:'HH.mm'}}'de paylaşıldı</mat-card-subtitle>
      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
        <p class="text-sm">{{review.comment}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</mat-dialog-content>```
------------------------------------------

What do i need to do to make the data appear on the dialog page? I want the path to change according to the post id.
                                          .
````

Comment: what have you tried so far friend